# The best way for caching data in MVC 3 and EF 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, output-caching, data-caching

Which is the best way to caching data and page's output (both) in ASP.NET MVC 3 and EF 4?
Is there any framework|library to this?
Thanks to all;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC already provides output caching - check [OutputCacheAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx) action filter. EF4 itself doesn't have any caching available but you can check [caching wrapper](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32) to add caching of query results.